What is this part for my flare making jig/tool
Getting ready to soak my flare-making tool in some vinegar to clean up the rust.
I have the clamp too but it's painted and does not need fixing.
My question is: What is the thing I'm holding here used for? It's clearly setup to put into the rail and screw down to hold it tight, but it's not clear to me what it does...

